# How to obtain an array that contains eponymous empty array [] using JSONpath syntax?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I need to achieve recursively the last block of json-tree.
(How do i understand that level is last in my case? It is the only that contains empty array `Positions:[]`).

```
{
"LocalVars": null,
"ColorString": "#FFFF4500",
"Type": 3,
"Id": "2021a2d3-99e1-3f5e-b294-3a08466af6ae",
"ExternalGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"FullTotalCost": 0.0,
"Factor": 1.0,
"IsActive": true,
"IsFinite": false,
"CatalogId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"CatalogName": "class1",
"Positions": [
  {
    "LocalVars": null,
    "ColorString": "#FFA52A2A",
    "Type": 0,
    "Id": "3d34e975-6e0c-0d97-a427-3a0846789047",
    "ExternalGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "FullTotalCost": 0.0,
    "Factor": 1.0,
    "Elements": [],
    "ElementGuids": null,
    "IsActive": false,
    "IsFinite": false,
    "CatalogId": "0bf4816d-8cef-6b8a-bc38-3a084678129a",
    "CatalogName": "class1",
    "Positions": [
    {
        "LocalVars": null,
        "ColorString": "#FFA52A2A",
        "Type": 3,
        "Id": "3d34e975-6e0c-0d97-a427-3a0846789047",
        "ExternalGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "FullTotalCost": 0.0,
        "Factor": 1.0,
        "IsActive": true,
        "IsFinite": false,
        "CatalogId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "CatalogName": "class1",
        "Positions":[
        {
            "LocalVars": null,
            "ColorString": "#FF0000CD",
            "Type": 0,
            "Id": "4687c792-9f46-457f-1171-3a08468257c3",
            "ExternalGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "FullTotalCost": 0.0,
            "Factor": 1.0,
            "IsActive": true,
            "IsFinite": true,
            "CatalogId": "b0cb7cca-84b5-5fd0-0fa0-3a0846822787",
            "CatalogName": "class1",
            "Positions": [],
            "Code": "1",
            "ValueCost": 0.0,
            "TotalCost": 0.0,
            "PositionValues": {
              "m2": {
                "RoundingDegree": 4,
                "Price": 0.0,
                "Type": "Square",
                "Unit": "m2",
                "Value": 186.8423,
                "CurrencyRate": 1.0,
                "CurrencyCharCode": "USD",
                "IsActive": false
              }
            },
            "Name": "Mullion panes",
            "PositionsCount": 222,
            "AllPositionsCount": 0,
            "RoundingDegree": 4,
            "IsEmpty": false,
            "FailureStatus": null,
            "LocalVars": {}
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
]
```

}

Then i need to retrieve from json-tree this block using .SelectTokens("JSONpath query")

```
"Positions":[
        {
            "LocalVars": null,
            "ColorString": "#FF0000CD",
            "Type": 0,
            "Id": "4687c792-9f46-457f-1171-3a08468257c3",
            "ExternalGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "FullTotalCost": 0.0,
            "Factor": 1.0,
            "IsActive": true,
            "IsFinite": true,
            "CatalogId": "b0cb7cca-84b5-5fd0-0fa0-3a0846822787",
            "CatalogName": "class1",
            "Positions": [],
            "Code": "1",
            "ValueCost": 0.0,
            "TotalCost": 0.0,
            "PositionValues": {
              "m2": {
                "RoundingDegree": 4,
                "Price": 0.0,
                "Type": "Square",
                "Unit": "m2",
                "Value": 186.8423,
                "CurrencyRate": 1.0,
                "CurrencyCharCode": "USD",
                "IsActive": false
              }
            },
            "Name": "Mullion panes",
            "PositionsCount": 222,
            "AllPositionsCount": 0,
            "RoundingDegree": 4,
            "IsEmpty": false,
            "FailureStatus": null,
            "LocalVars": {}
            ]
        }
```

I use newtonsoft nuget package to operate with json.

What am I doing? First i got JToken from json-string

```
var jTokenAnalysis = JToken.Parse(analysis)
```

Then i try to obtain what i need recursevly using JSONpath syntax in method .SelectTokens

```
var jTokenUnionResults = jTokenAnalysis
            .SelectTokens("$..[?(@.Positions.length() == 0)]");
```

And got empty json, but it shouldn't be.

I've already tried different JSONpath-queries like:

```
"$..[?(@.Positions&& @.Positions.length == 0)]"
"$..['Positions'][?(@.length == 0)]"
```

Could you help me with query or offer another way to obtain what i need?

Comment: Could you replace your link to an image of your data with the actual data so that it can be copied, please? Having an image makes it hard to grab the data for use in an evaluator.

Comment: Try `$..Positions[?(@.Positions[0] == null)]`

Comment: @Akshay G
did not work :(

Comment: Newtonsoft's implementation of JSONPath does does not support querying array length, see [Unable to use JSONPath expressions like @.length #1318](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1318#issuecomment-302944041): *`@.length` on arrays isn't supported.*  Do you require a JSONPath solution, or would a workaround using LINQ be sufficient?

Comment: If you're open to using JsonPath.Net, which is supported by System.Text.Json (not Newtonsoft), and is compliant with the upcoming IETF specification, you can use `$..[?length(@.Positions)==0]` to get values that contain `Positions: []`.  For your data, the value exists at `$['Positions'][0]['Positions'][0]['Positions'][0]`.  You can try it out at https://json-everything/json-path.  (Also your JSON is invalid and needs some fixing.)

Comment: you have invalid JSON. please remove ']' after last LocalVars

Answer (score 0):

SelectTokens jsonpath is not working correctly with arrays.
i would mix with linq

```cs
    string myJsonPath = "$..Positions[?(@.Positions != null)]";
    var obj = JObject.Parse(json)
                .SelectTokens(myJsonPath, false)
                .Where(w => ((JArray)w["Positions"]).Count == 0)
```

[image]

**also, you have extra character in json**